# Debugging miscompile

Tags: compiler, debugging, assembly, books

Recently I encountered an issue at work where a unit test written in C++ would crash only when being compiled with MSVC 2017 (MSVC 2019 and up are fine). I tried to debug this issue and it seems like a compiler bug causes memory corruption (e.g. the stack of a thread became corrupted at some point: the return address of a frame several levels below the current frame was overridden by some instructions in Microsoft STL). I can see the problem is not miscompiling that certain function since MSVC 2019 gave the same result. Maybe it is related to `std::move` passing the address from previous frame but a bug (miscompile?) causes the store overwrites something it shouldn't?

I didn't solve the issue and we decided to drop MSVC 2017 since it was already end of life. But I'm wondering how can I get better debugging issues like this? I'm new to this project and I'm not familiar with the source code of the area where the crash happened. So if I'm more familiar with the source I maybe able to guess and write better and smaller example to try to reproduce the issue. But what if I just want to figure it out with a debugger and disassemble? Anyone figured out compiler bugs would share their experience?

A little bit more background: the unit test is in a project which uses our project. And they only run into this issue because of a new release from us. It's possible to bisect the whole release and find out the source that causes the breakage. But it would be time consuming and wasn't the thing I have tried this time.

Comment: Hint: 99% of the time when devs say "it's a compiler bug", the program is inducing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8):

> Anyone figured out compiler bugs would share their experience?

In my 30+ years of programming, the only compiler bugs I’ve ever encountered were when I was working on the compiler.

What you’re describing is (very likely) a garden variety buffer overflow. Some code somewhere (that might not be temporally or spatially near the code that fails) overwrites its memory space and onto the stack.

This might be triggered by some optimizations that change how/where things are run. It also might be a configuration difference - debug mode on many compilers initializes allocated memory with zeros or a specific pattern to make identification easier.

Either way, the compiler is simply exposing a bug in your code that was already there.

Comment: I think it is very likely this assessment of the OPs case is correct, but let me add I can  remember a few rare occasions in the last decades where I stumbled about real compiler bugs (verified by inspecting the generated assembly code!). The latest one I remember was a crash with range-based for loops when this was a new feature in MSVC++ (I think it was in MSVC++ 2012). MS fixed it a few versions later. From this (and former cases) I can only recommend against using always the "latest and greatest" C++ features immediately with the first compiler version supporting those ...

Comment: ... features, but hold you breath and wait one or two years(!) before using such features for critical production code.